# codeigniter controller loading

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, load

I have a controller named **blog.php** in my localhost. To access it I type **http://localhost/ci/index.php/blog** in addressbar. In the tutorial it said that it will display **Hello World** but the display I got is a page containing the blog.php code and 404 Page Not Found.

Here is the code.

```
*<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/blog
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/blog/index
     *  - or -  
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/blog/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
/* End of file Blog.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/blog.php */*
```

anyone please help me to know what's the problem.

Comment: Can you post the config/config.php file code? And also is http://localhost/ci/ working? What does it display? And also you are not using the * before PHP, right?

Comment: yes Mr.web is right.Your codeigniter files inside ci folder?Try to serach at google or SO with same problem you will find lots of questions and answers.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of CodeIgniter are you using because the CI_Controller is for the older version on CI. Did you try to do

```
class Blog extends Controller {
}
```

or

```
class Blog extends MY_Controller {
}
```

Where MY_ is setted in your config.php file.

Comment: Actually not true. CI Uses CI_Controller still up to 2.1.4. MY_ is for the creation of own Classes and not controllers/views/models